# Confusing thing about the center of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$C(z) = \{ z' = gzg^{-1}, g\in G \}$.  So if $z$ is in the center of $G$ then $C(z) = \{1\}$, but if $C(z) = \{1\}$, then $gzg^{-1} =1$ for any $g$ in the group, solving makes $z = 1$, so the center is always trivial.  Doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$z$ is in the center of the group if and only if $C(z) = \{z\}$. To see this,

$$z \in C(z) \iff gz = zg \,\,\forall g \iff gzg^{-1} = z \,\,\forall g \iff C(z) = \{z\}$$

Comment: That makes sense but where did mine fail :\ ?

Comment: Because $C(z) = \{1\}$ doesn't always hold - in fact, it can *only* hold if $z = 1$.

Comment: If $z$ is in the center then $gzg^{-1} = 1$ though.

Comment: No, if $z$ is in the center, then $gzg^{-1} = z$.

Comment: @EnjoysMath No. If $z$ is a central element, it commutes with $g$, leading to $gzg^{-1} = z g g^{-1} = z 1 = z$.